# How to style RShiny switchInput when it is inside a uiOutput?

Tags: r, shiny, tags, shinywidgets

I've previously used the following style tags in my UI to style a switchInput from ShinyWidgets:

```
#switchInput color while on
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-danger,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-danger {
                                        background: #eef4fa;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
  
  #switchInput color while off
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #fdf1f1;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
```

However, now that I have rendered the switches as a uiOutput and then renderUI, it seems that these tags are not recognised.

How do I style the on and off versions of the switch when they are made via uiOutput rather than just put directly into the ui?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(bslib)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #switchInput color while on
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-danger,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-danger {
                                        background: #eef4fa;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
  
  #switchInput color while off
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #fdf1f1;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),

  
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           offset = 5,
           align = "center",
           uiOutput('log_axis_output')
    )),
    

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$log_axis_output <- renderUI({
    
    switchInput(
      inputId = "log_axis1",
      offLabel = "Log X\naxis?",
      onLabel = "Normal\nX axis",
      value = FALSE,
      offStatus = "success", 
      onStatus = "danger",
      disabled = FALSE)
    
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem with the R code. It's the problem with your CSS code.

Your CSS selectors don't have enough priority as the original style selectors.

to fix, change to following:

```r
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-danger,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-container .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-danger {
                                        background: #eef4fa;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
    
    #switchInput color while off
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-container .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-success {
                                        background: #fdf1f1;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
```

I added the `.bootstrap-switch-container` in the middle to increase the specificity level. Read more about how to calculate [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Another way is to use `!important`, but it is not generally recommended.

[image]

[image]